# how does Chrome DevTools knows content size of an incomplete http response

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chunked-encoding, http-content-length, http-chunked

I got an har file exported by Chrome DevTools. It shows an incomplete http response with error `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`. the incomplete http response has been transfered 4096 bytes.

```
 "content": {
        "size": 67469,
        "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
        "compression": 63629
      },
      "redirectURL": "",
      "headersSize": 256,
      "bodySize": 3840,
      "_transferSize": 4096,
      "_error": "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING"
    },
```

**My questing is how does Chrome DevTools know that the http response's content size 67469 bytes as the responese is INCOMPLETE?**

Here is the whole request record by Chrome DevTools(Sensitive infos is replaced):

```
{
    "_initiator": {
      "type": "script",
      "stack": {
        "callFrames": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "parentId": {
          "id": "4",
          "debuggerId": "xxx.-xxx"
        }
      }
    },
    "_priority": "High",
    "_resourceType": "fetch",
    "cache": {},
    "connection": "24665",
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "http://www.example.com?hello=world",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Accept",
          "value": "*/*"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept-Encoding",
          "value": "gzip, deflate"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept-Language",
          "value": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
          "name": "Connection",
          "value": "keep-alive"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cookie",
          "value": "..."
        },
        {
          "name": "Host",
          "value": "www.example.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pragma",
          "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
          "name": "Referer",
          "value": "http://www.example.com/ref?hello=world"
        },
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.50"
        }
      ],
      "queryString": [
        {
          "name": "hello",
          "value": "world"
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [1, 2, 3, 4],
      "headersSize": 2273,
      "bodySize": 0
    },
    "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "OK",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "private"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Disposition",
          "value": "attachment;FileName=example.pdf"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "Wed, 22 Feb 2023 17:10:05 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Server",
          "value": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Transfer-Encoding",
          "value": "chunked"
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [],
      "content": {
        "size": 67469,
        "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
        "compression": 63629
      },
      "redirectURL": "",
      "headersSize": 256,
      "bodySize": 3840,
      "_transferSize": 4096,
      "_error": "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING"
    },
    "serverIPAddress": "1.1.1.1",
    "startedDateTime": "2023-02-22T17:10:08.836Z",
    "time": 130.23999985307455,
    "timings": {
      "blocked": 9.5169998755157,
      "dns": -1,
      "ssl": -1,
      "connect": -1,
      "send": 0.556,
      "wait": 66.90000020015239,
      "receive": 53.266999777406454,
      "_blocked_queueing": 3.2859998755156994,
      "_blocked_proxy": 0.8559999999999999
    }
  },
```

The incomplete http above is produced by other people. An I try to reproduce it but failed. I make up a incomplete http response which has the first chunk(chunk-size CRLF chunk-data CRLF) and **no last-chunk('0' CRLFCRLF)**. Chrome DevTools show:

```
          "content": {
            "size": 0,
            "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
            "compression": 0
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 280,
          "bodySize": 0,
          "_transferSize": 280,
          "_error": "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING"
```

**My questing is how to reproduce the incomplete http response scenario which Chrome DevTools knows the content size?**

```
{
  "_initiator": {
    "type": "script",
    "stack": {
      "callFrames": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      "parentId": {
        "id": "4",
        "debuggerId": "-xxxx.-xxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "_priority": "High",
  "_resourceType": "fetch",
  "cache": {},
  "connection": "75735",
  "pageref": "page_1",
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "http://localhost:8085/HelloAshx.ashx",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Accept",
        "value": "*/*"
      },
      {
        "name": "Accept-Encoding",
        "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
      },
      {
        "name": "Accept-Language",
        "value": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "no-cache"
      },
      {
        "name": "Connection",
        "value": "keep-alive"
      },
      {
        "name": "Host",
        "value": "localhost:8085"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pragma",
        "value": "no-cache"
      },
      {
        "name": "Referer",
        "value": "http://localhost:8085/Home/About"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
        "value": "empty"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
        "value": "cors"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
        "value": "same-origin"
      },
      {
        "name": "User-Agent",
        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
      },
      {
        "name": "sec-ch-ua",
        "value": "\"Chromium\";v=\"110\", \"Not A(Brand\";v=\"24\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"110\""
      },
      {
        "name": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
        "value": "?0"
      },
      {
        "name": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
        "value": "\"Windows\""
      }
    ],
    "queryString": [],
    "cookies": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "headersSize": 923,
    "bodySize": 0
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "private"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Disposition",
        "value": "attachment;FileName=example.pdf"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/octet-stream"
      },
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "value": "Wed, 01 Mar 2023 13:52:37 GMT"
      },
      {
        "name": "Server",
        "value": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Transfer-Encoding",
        "value": "chunked"
      },
      {
        "name": "X-AspNet-Version",
        "value": "4.0.30319"
      },
      {
        "name": "X-Powered-By",
        "value": "ASP.NET"
      }
    ],
    "cookies": [],
    "content": {
      "size": 0,
      "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
      "compression": 0
    },
    "redirectURL": "",
    "headersSize": 280,
    "bodySize": 0,
    "_transferSize": 280,
    "_error": "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING"
  },
  "serverIPAddress": "[::1]",
  "startedDateTime": "2023-03-01T13:52:37.583Z",
  "time": 3.81499994546175,
  "timings": {
    "blocked": 0.6999999288022518,
    "dns": -1,
    "ssl": -1,
    "connect": -1,
    "send": 0.137,
    "wait": 1.2820000245794654,
    "receive": 1.6959999920800328,
    "_blocked_queueing": 0.3269999288022518
  }
}
```

Comment: In chunked transfer encoding, the size of each chunk is supplied as [part of the content body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#chunked) before the payload itself.

Comment: The incomplete http above is produced by other people. An I try to reproduce it but failed. I make up a incomplete http response which has the first chunk(chunk-size CRLF chunk-data CRLF) and no last-chunk('0' CRLFCRLF). Chrome DevTools show:
```
          "content": {
            "size": 0,
            "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
            "compression": 0
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 280,
          "bodySize": 0,
          "_transferSize": 280,
          "_error": "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING"
```